# SquidGuard and Active Directory: how to deal with multiple groups?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, groups, squid

I'm setting up SquidGuard (1.4) to validate users against an Active Directory domain and apply ACLs based on group membership; this is an example of my squidGuard.conf:

```
src AD_Group_A {
        ldapusersearch  ldap://my.dc.name/dc=domain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(sAMAccountName=%s)(memberOf=cn=Group_A%2cdc=domain%2cdc=com))
}

src AD_Group_B {
        ldapusersearch  ldap://my.dc.name/dc=domain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(sAMAccountName=%s)(memberOf=cn=Group_B%2cdc=domain%2cdc=com))
}

dest dest_a {
    domainlist  dest_a/domains
    urllist     dest_b/urls
    log     dest_a.log
}

dest dest_b {
    domainlist  dest_b/domains
    urllist     dest_b/urls
    log     dest_b.log
}

acl {
    AD_Group_A {
        pass    dest_a !dest_b all
        redirect http://some.url
    }

    AD_Group_B {
        pass    !dest_a dest_b all
        redirect http://some.url
    }

    default {
        pass    !dest_a !dest_b all
        redirect http://some.url
    }
}
```

All works fine if an user is member of Group_A *OR* Group_B. But if an user is member of *BOTH* groups, only the first source rule is evaluated, thus applying only the first ACL.

I understand this is due to how source rule matching works in SquidGuard (if one rule matches, evaluation stops there and then the related ACL is applied); so I tried this, too:

```
src AD_Group_A_B {
        ldapusersearch  ldap://my.dc.name/dc=domain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(sAMAccountName=%s)(memberOf=cn=Group_A%2cdc=domain%2cdc=com))
        ldapusersearch  ldap://my.dc.name/dc=domain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(sAMAccountName=%s)(memberOf=cn=Group_B%2cdc=domain%2cdc=com))
}

acl {
    AD_Group_A_B {
        pass    dest_a dest_b all
        redirect http://some.url
    }

    [...]
}
```

But this doesn't work, too: if an user is member of either one of those groups, the whole source rule is matched anyway, so he can reach both destinations (which is of course not what I want).

The only solution I found so far is creating a *THIRD* group in AD, and assign a source rule and an ACL to it; but this setup grows exponentially with more than two or three destination sets.

Is there any way to handle this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved... partially. I had totally overlooked the fact that you can add *another* condition to the LDAP query... so it's quite easy to check for membership of more than one group.

Some caveats:

- It's still necessary to define a SquidGuard ACL for every possible combination of groups
- You need to add at least two other directives to the SquidGuard configuration: `ldapbinddn` (which defines the username to use to connect to AD, and you have to use the DN of the user object here, not the plain username!) and `ldapbindpass`, which defines the user's password.
- SquidGuard needs to be compiled with LDAP support, which is not compiled in by default.

…but at least the actual groups in AD can be kept to a minimum.